# How to rotate image slowly in android?

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, rotation

I want to rotate an Image in a slow way on Android.
I can do this by creating a Bitmap and by the
help of of Matrix class. But i don't know how to make it slow, like it should take 3 seconds to rotate.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your question is not clear please . By rotation what you mean animation or  tilting of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rotate**

Rotate animation uses  tag. For rotate animation required tags are `android:fromDegrees` and `android:toDegrees` which defines rotation angles.

**Clock wise** – use positive toDegrees value

**Anti clock wise** – use negative toDegrees value

rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="600"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/cycle_interpolator"/>

</set>
```

Save in anim folder

[image]

```
public class AnimationActivity extends Activity{

    ImageView img;
    Animation rotate;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fadein);

        img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageid);

        // load the animation
        rotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.rotate);
        img.startAnimation(rotate);

    }
}
```

[Complete Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations)

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin you can use the [ObjectAnimator](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/reposition-view#UseObjectAnimator) do this super easily. For example:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "rotationX", 180f).apply {
duration = 2000
start()
}
```

- **view**: the view you want to rotate
- **"rotationX"**: the propertyName you want to alter.
  "rotationX" gives you rotation into and out of the screen
  "rotationY" gives you clockwise/counterclockwise rotation
- **180f**: how many degrees you want to rotate the view
- **duration**: the number of milliseconds the animation should take to complete

Answer (score 0):

You can use rotate animation to achieve this.

Create anim folder under res directoy inside that place this xml.

rotate_around_center_point.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <rotate
        android:duration="2500"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="restart"
        android:toDegrees="360" />

</set>
```

Set animation to view like this.

```
ImageView animationTarget = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.testImage);
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate_around_center_point);
animationTarget.startAnimation(animation);
```

Comment: how much duration you want to animate you can change from the xm.